# What happens under the hood when I type "Node server.js"

Tags: node.js

Is this an "instance" of Node? What special provisions from the OS does a node instance get?

Comment: It runs the "server.js" file. It's not clear what you're asking. Node just runs JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if there is one big process of node, that executes all the scripts, or if each script is executed by its own instance, the answer is the second.

Each script has its own node instance. As far as I know, each instance has the same provisions as bash, python, perl, etc would have.

Try to do `ps ax|grep node` to see the current instances in execution.